# Unity - Particle Effects: How can I make the Shader play in the desired time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, particle-system

Lately I've been trying out my luck on VFX. I've come across effect that I like very much, the Scrolling Shader.

I was basing myself on [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/ftp0s8/scrolling_energy_shader_breakdown/) and managed to get in touch with it's creator, so shoutout to him, and he guided me in the right direction to achieve the desired effect.

Later, I realized I had a few errors that, if someone can help me with, I would much appreciate it.

The effect is simply the texture scrolling through a certain mesh, masked with a alpha texture.

First issue: The effect has no color... It rotates and the alpha mask is fixed but the color does not show.

Second issue: I'm using this shader to complete a specific part of an effect, using the Particle System. I used the Color Over Lifetime option but it still activates as soon as the whole effect starts. With the Start Delay option, it works.

In a way the problem is fixed this way, altough I would like to know how I could this slowly appearing like the Color Over Lifetime.

Final question as in more of a bonus.

Is there a way to slowly making the mesh appear, alongside the shader effect, from bottom to top?

Current Shader code

```
Shader "Custom/ScrollingShader"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _AlphaMaskTex ("AlphaMask", 2D) = "white" {}
        _ScrollSpd ("Scroll Speeds", vector) = (-5, -20, 0, 0)
        [HDR] _Color ("Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
        // No culling or depth
        Cull back ZWrite Off ZTest Always Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha


        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float2 alphauv : TEXCOORD1;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            float4 _AlphaMaskTex_ST;
            float4 _ScrollSpd;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {                
                /* v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex).xy + frac(_Time.y * float2(_ScrollSpd.x, _ScrollSpd.y));
                return o; */

                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex).xy + frac(_Time.y * float2(_ScrollSpd.x, _ScrollSpd.y));

                o.alphauv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _AlphaMaskTex).xy;

                return o;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            sampler2D _AlphaMaskTex;
            float4 _Color;

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                fixed4 colA = tex2D(_AlphaMaskTex, i.alphauv);

                col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) * _Color;

                col.a = tex2D(_AlphaMaskTex, i.uv).r;

                col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) * tex2D(_AlphaMaskTex, i.alphauv).r;

                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Mesh used with material applied:

[image]

Thanks in advance and if there's something that you don't understand, please bring it to me so I can try to explain better.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

regarding your first question:
In line 68

> col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) * _Color;

You are trying to set the color by multiplying the texture with your color.
In line 72

> col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) * tex2D(_AlphaMaskTex, i.alphauv).r;

You are just overwriting your existing color values. So as long as your base texture is grayscale there will be no color in the effect. I am guessing you want something like this:

```
col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) * _Color;
//col.a = tex2D(_AlphaMaskTex, i.alphauv).r; //<-- Edit1
col.a = tex2D(_AlphaMaskTex, i.alphauv).r * _Color.a; //<-- Edit2 fade in
```

Regarding your second question: 
I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve. I am also not an expert on the Particle system. But as long as you are drawing your particles the shader will be executed and by referencing _Time it will be animated. The color over lifetime can be used as an input for your shader. So you can use this as a value to change your shader behaviour. You can do all kinds of fun stuff, for example if you wanted to start animating the particle after a while you could setup the color over lifetime to blend from 0 alpha to 1 alpha then you check the alpha value in the shader and if its greater than 0.5 you start to animate your uvs. The color over lifetime function seems like a good way to pass data to your shader.

Unfortunately i don't really understand what you are trying to achieve so i can't really help more. Maybe you can elaborate on your second question?

Regarding your third question:

This is totally possible. In your fragment shader you can think of your uvs to be a gradient from bottom to top and left to right. So if you take uv.y and multiply it to your alpha color you will be blending your particle. Now you can animate this with the color you got from your color over time function. I haven't tried it but you could do something like this:

```
col.a = clamp(col.a * i.uv.y + _Color.a, 0.0f, 1.0f); //<- Edit
```

Like I've said I didn't test this and you will most like need to add some offsets to this. If you are struggling I can see if I can give you a running example.

Comment: Hello @Witt

Thank you for the answer!

Regarding the first answer, I tried do that but that makes the alpha texture move upwards as well. Which makes something like [this](https://imgur.com/xiYW2qn)
Instead of [this](https://imgur.com/0bd3lQy).

I don't know if that's what I'm looking for. I must say I'm quite new to this.
What I mean is, Color Over Lifetime can change the transparency as well. In this effect, it completely ignores the transition, as in, when the animation was suppose to play (after the Start Delay), it immediately appears instead of slowly coming appearing.

Comment: Got out of characters, need to be a double commentary.

The third one, it creates [this waves](https://imgur.com/clVwCuK) and I don't think the offset will help on this but I might be wrong. Also, no idea on how to add offsets in shader scripting.

I thank you a lot for your answer!

Best of luck!

Comment: I overlooked that you had different uvs for alpha and the main texture. In my example code I used the uvs to sample the alpha. I changed it to your alphauv. I edited the answer. Now it should look the same like your image but with colors. If you want to get a similar effect to the post you linked. You will need to set the color to a hdr color, to get bright whites and a nice color gradient like flames.

Comment: about the slowly appearing problem: You are layering multiple alpha values. Currently the alpha value of the _Color is discarded by "col.a = tex2D(_AlphaMaskTex, i.alphauv).r;" you are overwriting it with a new alpha. If you want to fade in with the color over time you will need to multiply it to the value ;) - I'll edit an example into the original answer.

Comment: For your third problem: This is a little hard to explain you need to combine the functions to get the desired result. The y uvs are your top down gradient, to move them you just add an offset. If the offset is your animated alpha value the whole thing will move. Here is an example in shadertoy: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/3djBR3
you can do similar in unity.

Comment: Hello again!

I'm really sorry for the late response. Stack didn't notified me... Really really sorry

Since I don't have access right now to the project, I can't change it but I will.

I thank you for all the help and I'm really sorry for the late response.